# MS Access through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, activex, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble with a well-known problem but I can't find any solutions. I have an old application (I don't know how old exactly) written in VBA using Excel which uses some Access data (*.mdb). The application was written on a 32-bit system. I tried to update it to the new 64-bit system using Office 2010.

Here is the code I use to load the Access DB: 
    `Set Db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(.sChemin & .sNom, False, False, ";pwd=******")`

And the error I get: 
    `429 Activex Component Cant Create Object`

Here are my references:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Data Access Components Installed Version
- Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

I have already tried to unregister / re-register the DAO dll using `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\dao360.dll"`, and I got the same problem when I try to use workspaces.

I don't know if it's gonna help but Access is working fine when I use the CreateObject("Access.Application") and I installed Excel / Word and Access at two different times.

Comment: Is office 2010 64bit? or just the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the reference to `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`, it is very old. Add a reference to `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library`.

Comment: I tryed that but then I've got a whole lot of undefined types such as "Recordset". I'm not very familiar with VBA to it will give me trouble to rewrite the whole application. However I do know that this application work as it is on my colleague's computer, running windows Xp and the same office 2010. Can I by any change get some others / olders libraries from it ?

Comment: Look at the references your colleague has. Make sure you have the same references. Make sure that none of them are marked missing.

Comment: Don't mind it, i've started to rewrite the whole thing with .Net and mysql. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Could you explain how you know that DAO 3.6 is causing the problem? I.e. how do you know that DBEngine is defined in DAO 3.6? And how do you know that "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library" has same/similar functionality?

Comment: @dainichi because the OP says they are using Access 2010.

Comment: @Fionnuala, thanks, but that doesn't help me much. I guess my question more specifically is: Is there a specific way (API documents, maybe) to identify DAO 3.6 as the reference defining the Object DBEngine, and would there be documents saying this is deprecated and replaced by "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library"?

Comment: DAO 3.6 is Jet, this was re-developed as ACE for 2007 version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine. There is nothing wrong with 3.6 if you are using VBScript 32 bit or earlier versions of MS Access with Jet. You can use earlier versions of MS Access with ODBC and the ACE connections string.